# How to change this code to be written in angular?

Tags: jquery, angular, angular5, angular6

So I've been using jQuery alongside with Angular which turns out not to be a good practice, that's why I'm trying to edit my code not to use jQuery again in this Angular App

so I have a page of menu items which fetches data from the server and I loop on an array of items to display the data,

each Item should have a counter to increase or decrease the quantity to send it to a cart so it has to be specific for each Item,

right Now I'm using an Id on the element that contains a string-index (num-1) and I'm binding a click event on an increase button like follows

```
increase(id) {
  let oVal = parseInt($('#item-' + id).html());
  if (oVal < this.maxNumber) {
    $('#item-' + id).html(oVal + 1);
  }
}
```

html

```
<div class="spinner m-2">
  <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary up" (click)="increase(item.product_id)">
      <i class="ic-add"></i>
  </a>
  <label id="item-{{item.product_id}}" class="count">
    1
  </label>
  <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary down" (click)="decrease(item.product_id)">
      <i class="ic-substract"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

So how to change this to use angular instead of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You should maintain 'counter' property in each item object. We need to increase/decrease the counter value when user press +/-. So those update should apply to that particular item object.

```
elements = [{
...
quantity:1
},{
...
quantity:0
},{
...
quantity:0
}]

increase(itemObj) {
  if (itemObj.quantity < this.maxNumber) {
    itemObj.quantity++;
  }
} 

decrease(itemObj) {
  if (itemObj.quantity >0) {
    itemObj.quantity--;
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not get it,, I do not have such property !

Comment: instead of counter property. you can have quantity and display the value in the template.

Answer (score 0):

please check that.

```
increase(id) {
  var strId = 'item-' + id
  let oVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(strId).innerHTML);
  if (oVal < this.maxNumber) {
    var ovalIncrement:any = oVal + 1
    document.getElementById(strId).innerHTML = ovalIncrement;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am again manipulating DOM with javascript that is not angular way

Comment: you said that you want to convert?

Comment: to angular way not javascipt like using ViewChild or renderer2

Comment: with that code we can't help you.please show your .ts file and html file

Answer (score 0):

You haven't show what your array of data looks like but lets say it looks like this:

```
myArray = [
  {
    name: 'item1',
    product_id: 'aaa'
  },
  {
    name: 'item2',
    product_id: 'bbb'
  }
]
```

So now you want to add a quantity property which you can do like this:

```
this.myArray = this.myArray.map(item => {
  item.quantity = 0
  return item
})
```

So now your array looks like this:

```
myArray = [
  {
    name: 'item1',
    product_id: 'aaa',
    quantity: 0
  },
  {
    name: 'item2',
    product_id: 'bbb',
    quantity: 0
  }
]
```

So now you can iterate your array in your template like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of array">
  <div class="spinner m-2">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary up" (click)="increase(item)">
      <i class="ic-add"></i>
    </a>
    <label id="item-{{item.product_id}}" class="count">
      <span>{{ item.quantity }}</span>
    </label>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary down" (click)="decrease(item)">
      <i class="ic-substract"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

and in the controller .ts file:

```
increase(item) {
  if (item.quantity < this.maxNumber) {
    item.quantity ++
  }
}

decrease(item) {
  if (item.quantity > 0) {
    item.quantity --
  }
}
```